# Sinch Proguard can't find referenced class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService

Tags: android, firebase, sinch, android-sinch-api

I am using [Sinch Android Voice](https://developers.sinch.com/docs/voice-for-android) to place app to app calling. It's running fine in debug mode and as instructed in release mode Running proguard as given in [proguard-project.txt file](https://github.com/sinch/android-app-app-calling-headers/blob/master/proguard-project.txt).

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.**

-keep class com.sinch.** { *; }
-keep interface com.sinch.** { *; }
-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; }
```

But it gives error as

**can't find referenced class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService**

As googled above issue it was mentioned as FirebaseInstanceIdService has been removed from new Firebase sdk.

In my project I use latest firebase messaging gradle version as

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.3"
```

and Sinch voice sdk version

```
sinch-android-rtc-3.17.1.aar
```

[Sinch](https://developers.sinch.com/docs/voice-for-android) may be using old version of firebase messaging, if it's the case then how to use Sinch in release mode ?, is there any updated proguard or something ?

Comment: Check this it could be the problem https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2020-02-27

Comment: @IbrahimDisouki did check, it's not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinch SDK uses optional linking with Firebase, so after adding

```
-dontwarn com.sinch.**
```

resolved the issue.